# How to schedule a task once a week from a date decided by the user with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scheduled-tasks

I need to download some files weekly at a time and day specified by the user as shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZx5p.png).
I am struggling with integrating an inner loop with respect to `root.mainloop()`.
So far I have tried with `.after` and with a while structured like this:

```
def scaricaAuto(myDay, myHour, myMinute):
    while True:
    day = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A")
    hour = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H")
    minute = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%M")
    if day == myDay and str(int(hour)) == myHour and str(int(minute)) == myMinute:
       DownloadButton.invoke()
       break
    root.after(60000, scaricaAuto(clickedDays.get(), HourSpin.get(), MinSpin.get()))
```

Using only `.after` leads to `Python: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` and the while loop doesn't behave properly, when the if is true it gets stucked there and keeps invoking DownloadButton.

Also OS X shows my script to be "not responding" when a button function last longer than a few seconds, is there a solution for this to?

Thanks in advance to those that took the time to read my question and might be able to help me!

Comment: issue is with how you call the function, in the `root.after()` you call what `scariaAuto` function **returns**, first of that will make it run again recursively and then it will never stop and reach max recursion depth, to pass arguments do it like this: `root.after(60000, scaricaAuto, clickedDays.get(), HourSpin.get(), MinSpin.get())`, however this will require your python script to run the whole time , besides what is that `while True` loop? it shouldn't be there and also `datetime.datetime.now()` should be called only once. On windows the `cmd` has a command `schtasks` so look it up

Comment: @Matiiss if I try to pass arguments as you said I get  (` root.after(60000, scaricaAuto(), clickedDays.get(), HourSpin.get(), MinSpin.get())#scaricaAuto(clickedDays.get(), HourSpin.get(), MinSpin.get())) 
TypeError: scaricaAuto() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'myDay', 'myHour', and 'myMinute' `) . Also the while loop was an attempt to avoid using recursion since it doesn't work for me because I exceed the recursion depth. Thanks tough!

Comment: that is not how I told you to pass arguments, read carefully it should be this: `root.after(60000, scaricaAuto, clickedDays.get(), HourSpin.get(), MinSpin.get())` exactly like this, you don't need to call the function like you do

Comment: Omg, thank you very much, it works!! How do I make your comment the solution? Btw datetime.datetime.now() needs to be there everytime when the function is called because it compares the current time to the target time.

Comment: @you can do sth like `current_time = datetime.datetime.now()` and then access `current_time` such as `day = current_time.strftime("%A")`, that way you only need one function call. you don't need to make the comment a solution (nor it is possible), because this is probably answered somewhere already or in the documentation at least, I just came by and pointed out where you went wrong

Comment: @Matiiss that way the current time is not updated which is necessary for me. Thanks again for your help!!

Comment: even if you place it in the function? shouldn't it be then updated each time you call the function?

Comment: @Matiiss I see now what you mean. Instead of calling it 3 times per call you call it 1 time. It makes a lot of sense, thanks. I'm a beginner if you couldn't say lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code. First, you need to remove `while True`. That serves no purpose. Tkinter is already running an infinite loop by way of `mainloop`.

Second, `after` requires a function. You're calling a function and passing the result to `after`.

In other words, this:

```
root.after(60000, scaricaAuto(clickedDays.get(), HourSpin.get(), MinSpin.get()))
```

... is functionally identical to this:

```
result = scaricaAuto(clicedDays.get(), HourSpin.get(), MinSpin.get())
root.after(60000, result)
```

Instead, you either need to pass `scaricaAuto` as an argument, or you need to create a new function that calls your function. In the case of the former, you can pass arguments to the function by passing those arguments to `after`.

For example,

```
root.after(60000, scaricaAuto, clickedDays.get(), HourSpin.get(), MinSpin.get())
```

Note that this calls the `.get()` functions immediately rather than waiting the full 60 seconds.

A better solution is to not pass any arguments to `scaricaAuto` and instead have it call the `.get()` methods right when it needs the values:

```
def scaricaAuto():
    myDay = clickedDays.get()
    myHour = HourSpin.get()
    myMinute = MinSpin.get()

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    day = now.strftime("%A")
    hour = now.strftime("%H")
    minute = now.strftime("%M")

    if day == myDay and str(int(hour)) == myHour and str(int(minute)) == myMinute:
       DownloadButton.invoke()
    root.after(60000, scaricaAuto)
```

The above code will run for as long as the GUI itself is running, assuming you've called `mainloop` at some point.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works :) I can't upvote it because I am new on stackoverflow..

Comment: @AndreaPython But you can mark it as a correct answer

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now()` could be called only once and the value assigned to a variable as to not call it three times